# Adding a new node to xml-file depending on content of file

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform my xml-file and add to it a new node depending on content of my xml-file.
For example i have:

```
<sheet name="Sheet1" num="1">
<row num="3">
<cell num="1">FP1152</cell>
<cell num="2">1039_2</cell>
<cell num="3">FP000234</cell>
</row>
<row num="4">
<cell num="1">RT1152</cell>
<cell num="2">1039_1</cell>
<cell num="3">GL000235</cell>
</row>
<row num="6">
<cell num="1">FP1152</cell>
<cell num="2">1039_1</cell>
<cell num="3">FP000234</cell>
</row>

</sheet>
```

If i have the same value in the cells with same value of num atribute in different rows but different values in the another pair of cells(in my example it's rows with @num=3 and @num=6), I want to add a flag like this:

```
<sheet name="Sheet1" num="1">
<flag type="ambiguousSuplier">true<flag>
    <row num="3">
    <cell num="1">FP1152</cell>
    <cell num="2">1039_2</cell>
    <cell num="3">FP000234</cell>
    </row>
    <row num="4">
    <cell num="1">RT1152</cell>
    <cell num="2">1039_1</cell>
    <cell num="3">GL000235</cell>
    </row>
    <row num="6">
    <cell num="1">FP1152</cell>
    <cell num="2">1039_1</cell>
    <cell num="3">FP000234</cell>
    </row>

    </sheet>
```

Comment: Is it the cell with num = 1 that you use to compare rows. That is to say row with num = 4 has to be checked separately?

Comment: Yes, it is everything ok with row num=4, i need to firstly compare rows by cell num=1 and then (if cells with num=1 match) compare cells with num=3.

Comment: Will there only ever be three cells for each row? Or can you have an unlimited number?

Comment: I will have 6 cells for each row, i cut the example for simplicity, but I always compare only cells with num=1 and num=3

Answer (score 2):

If rows within a specific sheet are grouped by cells with a **@num** of 1 and 3, then one way I can think to do this is to group such cells by a key

```
<xsl:key 
 name="cells" 
 match="cell" 
 use="concat(../../@num, '|', ../cell[@num='1'], '|', ../cell[@num='3'], '|', @num)" />
```

This looks up cells by their sheet number, and cells 1 and 2 within the same row.

Then, you need to check whether a **sheet** contains a cell which itself contains a matching cell in the above key but with a different value. This is done by the following nasty looking statement

```
<xsl:template 
  match="sheet
    [row/cell
      [text() != 
      key('cells', 
        concat(../../@num, '|', ../cell[@num='1'], '|', ../cell[@num='3'], '|', @num))/text()]]">
```

So, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="cells" match="cell" use="concat(../../@num, '|', ../cell[@num='1'], '|', ../cell[@num='3'], '|', @num)" />

   <xsl:template match="sheet[row/cell[text() != key('cells', concat(../../@num, '|', ../cell[@num='1'], '|', ../cell[@num='3'], '|', @num))/text()]]">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <flag type="ambiguousSupplier">true</flag>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your given XML, the following is output

```
<sheet name="Sheet1" num="1">
   <flag type="ambiguousSupplier">true</flag>
   <row num="3">
      <cell num="1">FP1152</cell>
      <cell num="2">1039_2</cell>
      <cell num="3">FP000234</cell>
   </row>
   <row num="4">
      <cell num="1">RT1152</cell>
      <cell num="2">1039_1</cell>
      <cell num="3">GL000235</cell>
   </row>
   <row num="6">
      <cell num="1">FP1152</cell>
      <cell num="2">1039_1</cell>
      <cell num="3">FP000234</cell>
   </row>
</sheet>
```

I am sure there must be a simpler solution, so I wouldn't accept this answer just yet, even if it does solve your problem.....